# how to get the value from expression tag to javascript in jsp page for validation?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
             <a id=<%= id%> href="javascript:redirect()" >      
                 <img src=<%= s%> style="width:90px; height:90px;" />  
             </a>
         </td>
         <td>
             <p>Product Name  : <%= name %></p>
             <p>Product Price : <%= list.get(i).getProdPrice() %></p>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to get the value of `<%= id%>` in jsp code [`<a id=<%= id%> href="javascript:redirect()" >`] in my javascript. I am calling a javascript `redirect()`,

How can I get the value of `id` in my javascript? This is my javascript.

```
function redirect(){
    var a = document.getElementById("id").value;  
    alert(a);   
 }
```

I need to get the value in javascript function and need to submit the page from javascript.

I am using struts2 framework.

Comment: what value do you need here? the only element with id defined is the `<a href>` element which doesn't have any value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to pass the value <%= id%> to your javascript function. you can do this by making the following changes to your code

change the javascript function to :

```
 function redirect(id){
    alert(id);    /* or any other processing you need */
 }
```

and attach redirect in the JSP `as`

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>
             <a href="javascript:redirect(<%= id%>)" >      
                    <%-- CHANGE MADE ABOVE -- %>

                 <img src=<%= s%> style="width:90px; height:90px;" />  
             </a>
         </td>
         <td>
             <p>Product Name  : <%= name %></p>
             <p>Product Price : <%= list.get(i).getProdPrice() %></p>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You, Thanks a lot. Its working, i made the change as u mentioned and i am getting the value in my script.

Comment: Great! In the future try using unobtrusive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) JavaScript ;-)